# Yii CListView - Adding a manual item

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm using YiiBoostrap in my Yii app and I have a TbListView output some images.

```
<?php
        $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderModerator,
            'id'=>'website-grid',
            'itemView'=>'_viewWebsite',
            'template'=>'{items}',
            'itemsCssClass'=>'grid-group row m-t-25',
            'cssFile'=>false,
            'summaryText'=>false,
            'pager'=>array(
                'header'=>'',
                'cssFile'=>false,
                'maxButtonCount'=>10,
                'selectedPageCssClass'=>'active',
                'hiddenPageCssClass'=>'disabled',
                'prevPageLabel'=>'&lsaquo;',
                'nextPageLabel'=>'&rsaquo;',
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'')));
?>
```

**Output**

[image]

I would like to add a div manually to the end of above generated lists, which I'm expecting something like this

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: What purpose of this div will be?

Comment: Opening a Modal to add a new item on click

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `'template'=>'{items}',` property by adding custom HTML with element:

```
'template'=>'{items}<div id="my_custom_element">Foo bar</div>',
```

or the same in more „elegant“ way:

```
// regarding your 'itemView'=>'_viewWebsite'
$item = $this->renderPartial('_viewWebsite', array(
    'your' => 'custom',
    'vari' => 'ables',
));
```

and

```
'template'=>'{items}'.$item,
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be possible with jQuery:

```
$('<div id="my_new_element">HUGE PLUS SIGN with all functionality</div>')
    .appendTo('#website-grid');
```

You can put this inside some JavaScript function and call it when needed. E.g. at first time or `afterAjaxUpdate` in your `TbListView`. This is just an idea. See how [create DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) and [CListView::afterAjaxUpdate()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView/#afterAjaxUpdate-detail).